# Read filtered log cat(Programmatically)?

Tags: android, logcat, log-level

How can i read filtered log cat where`Level` is Warning?

That's all i know....

```
logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d"});

br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcat.getInputStream()),4*1024);
String line;
  final StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
  String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
     {
       log.append(line);
         log.append(separator);
}
```

Comment: Heyy... Did u find any solution to this ??

Answer (score 1):

The -s flag lets you filter logcat output based on tag and level e,w,d,v so you can try modifying your line.

```
logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d","-s","*:w"});
```

Comment: when i use -s, buffered reader ends after reading first two lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (line.contains("WARN")) {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily filter the line that you want to write like the code below:

```
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("OkHttp")){
            log.append(line.substring(line.indexOf("OkHttp")));
            log.append('\n');}
            else{continue;}
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 try {
                  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
                  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                  StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
                  String line = "";
                  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    log.append(line);
                  }
                  TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                  tv.setText(log.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
```

Hope u get what u want....

Comment: is there any difference between codes written above?? I ASKED HOW TO FILTER THAT LOGCAT WHICH I AM READING? WHERE Level level = Level.WARNING;