# LogCat programatic filtering in Android

Tags: android, logcat

I want to create an arraylist of logcat data as follows: time level tag text .....
Example :

```
06-13 13:34:43:434 W myApp blehblehbleh
```

How do I filter the logcat to obtain this result? More precisely, what goes into the .exec(" ") part to get these values because "logcat -d" seems to get everything.

```
    log = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    try {

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            log.add(line);

     }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android - it demonstrates the parameters you can pass to logcat.

Comment: Yes I would assume "logcat -v tag" would retrieve me the tags but that doesn't work

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294820/applying-logcat-filter-programmatically) . I tried the answer given there. You can filter out tags only of your app from `logcat -d`

Answer (score 2):

This will print all the logs from YOUR_TAG_HERE and it will filter out the rest:

```
logcat -d YOUR_TAG_HERE:V *:S
```

Comment: ./adb logcat -d -v threadtime  works to get everything. How do I put this in the .exec() function

Answer (score 0):

You could simple to do a

```
if (line.contains("myApp")) log.add(line);
```

in your loop to only add lines from your app. In your current setup that seems like the quickest way.

Comment: ./adb logcat -d -v threadtime gets me everything I need. I just need to figure out the syntax for putting it in .exec()